# divide a fixed prize among an unknown number of contestants with repect to rank

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I want to divide a prize, say 1000, among an unknown number of contestants, as determined by their rank in a marathon race. I want the smallest portion to be above zero (so it is worthwhile to compete). So the higher the rank: the higher the prize.

PS, feel free to explain in detail as I am a math noob. Thanks.

PPS, I just made the marathon up to make the problem more familiar, but I guess real marathons actually are not even like that. My application is for a drag and drop stack of user interface elements, for which I want to have a gradient of values according to their sequence, above being higher value, below being lower value.

Update: this was simpler than I thought, and based on the comments, I came to a formula:

n = number of contestants
P = prize : 1000
r = current contestant rank
p = unknown portion

p = P(r/(n(n+1)/2))

But I would like to simplify this formula please if possible, cause I'll use it in programming

edit 2:
I got this far: P(r/(n(n+1)/2)) = 2Pr/(n(n+1))

Comment: How about this: Give the first person half the amount, the second person half what's left (i.e. a quarter of the initial amount), then next half of what's left, etc. This does assume that the amount is infinitely divisible.

Comment: Do the prizes have to be integer values? Is the prize fixed? You just need to set up a finite sequence of descending integers and use ratios to split the results. If you need an integer amount for each person, the prize value you can split is bound from below by the nth triangular number for n people. There are many ways to answer this problem, but it depends on your constraints. Descending ratios like 3:2:1 will work generally  if there are no constraints though. Split into parts the sum of the ratios and divide them as you chose.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, yes that would work, thanks. The only thing with that would be the distribution if one could see the curve, would be very curved, and I feel somehow, it should be straighter? I do want it to be worthwhile, even when there are a lot of contestants / items in the stack.

Comment: Jaap, that also assumes that the number of people is infinite. Otherwise you have a small amount of prize money left over. You could, however, split the leftover amount evenly between the last two people and the constraints would not be broken,

Comment: Yes, MediaMaker, just do what I suggested and set up a ratio of $n:n-1:...:3:2:1$ and split the prize evenly into $n(n+1)/2$ parts and delve up according to the ratios. My point was that it works for arbitrary sequences as long as they were descending. You are free to choose the degree to which they descend. In Jaap's example the sequence is descending powers of 2 but with a bit left over.

Comment: @ChrisMoorhead The prize is a fixed integer, it's I just made it up in order to do something with the weightings for the items in the stack. I'll use it to multiply against other metrics later for scoring the items. Thanks, I'll look into 'nth triangular number'

Comment: @MediaMaker What I mean is that the absolute smallest size for the prize is 1 for the lowest, 2 for the next... all the way to n for the winner if the individual assignments must be integers too. If your prize is smaller than this number, the problem is not doable. Play around with the ratios method I suggested above. If you can give two people the same amount of prize money it makes it slightly easier, but not always solvable in the general case if both the prize and the divisions must be integers.

Comment: @ChrisMoorhead wow, I had a feeling my question was dumb but I just realized reading your comment that you are right, it already has a straight weighting, implicit in the sequence, and since all I'm trying to do is get the relative weighting, we can disregard a fixed prize, and just let it be the sum of 1+2+3+4+5...+n where n is the total number of contestants. I think.

Comment: When you said "unknown number of contestants", I assumed that you didn't know how many contestants there were while you are handing out prizes. If you do know how many there are before you start distributing, it is indeed a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be interesting to formalize your thought: in fact, you want to distribute a certain amount a money, let's say 1000 (€!).

As you noticed in your previous message, it is strictly equivalent to create numbers between 0 and 1 and then multiply it by the total amount of money you want to distribute. The number - let's say P(n) - between 0 and 1 corresponds to the proportion of the total amount of money to attribute to the n-th finisher.

Another constraint is that the total amount of money distributed is equal to 1000 which is equivalent as distributing 100% of the money you have: the sum of the proportion must be equal to 1.

Finally, you want the first person to receive more than the second and so on.

In a mathematical way, your question is equivalent to ask which (discrete) probability you can take to fit your constraints: you need to restrict yourself to *discrete monotone probability*.

It is a really interesting subject, you might start to study probability to get the intuition behind the object (further study might include measure theory, a fascinating discipline).

Comment: Hi @celnaFR, thanks for your input. I am also a new contributor. I think everyone is underestimating just how bad at math I am, and how simple the problem was. It's not a probability question as far as I can see (not that it couldn't be. I'm sure it really does start to get interesting as a probability question). But thanks anyway for the tips :)

Answer (score 0):

Following my understanding of Chris Moorhead's comments, I'll try to answer this myself:

for 6 contestants

1+2+3+4+5+6

= 21

1/21 = .0476
2/21 = .0952
3/21 = .1428
4/21 = .1905
5/21 = .2381
6/21 = .2857
6/21+5/21+4/21+3/21+2/21+1/21 = 1
= sweet!

Then just multiply those decimal numbers against 1000 to get the portion of the prize for that contestant:

1000 * .0476 = 47.6
1000 * .0952 = 95.2
1000 * .1428 = 142.8
1000 * .1905 = 190.5
1000 * .2381 = 238.1
1000 * .2857 = 285.7

then check it adds up again:
47.6 + 95.2 + 142.8 + 190.5 + 238.1 + 285.7 = 999.9
close enough I think :)

Comment: Remember also that denominator can be calculated as $1+2+3+4+5+...+n = n(n+1)/2$.