# Divide x into y parts by decreasing value

Tags: algorithms

If I had $1000(variable) and I want to split that amount up and give it to 20(variable) people, but rather than give it evenly to each person, I want to give more to the 1st person, and the 2nd person, etc.

So the 20th person gets the least, and the 5th person gets the 5th most.

How would I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: You can do it many ways.  Just make a list of numbers you like, not worrying that they have to total 1000, then add them up and scale by 1000/sum.  There are formulas, but no reason to pick one over another except your taste.

Comment: @RossMillikan i'm not looking to have an average, i want each person to have a different amount based on their position in a list. First position having the most, and last person having the least, totalling 1000.

Comment: I understand that.  One way is to start by giving everybody $21-position$, but that sums to $231$, so multiply those by $\frac {1000}{231}$ and you have one approach.

Comment: Okay, but how would I set a total? How would I set my total to 1000 and my number of people to 20?

Comment: I said that.  The origitnal total is the sum of the numbers you pick.  In that example it is the sum of the numbers from $1$ to $20$, which is $231$.  You multiply each one by $\frac {1000}{231}$ and the total is then $1000$ as you wish.  But you could make the largest $50$ at the start if you want because you want a grand prize.  Then the original total is $\frac {1000}{261},$ so you multiply by that.

Comment: See also [divide a fixed prize among an unknown number of contestants with repect to rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184887/divide-a-fixed-prize-among-an-unknown-number-of-contestants-with-repect-to-rank#comment6554961_3184887).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this.

Say you have $x$ amount of things to distribute amongst $n$ people. One way to do it would be to let $k=\frac{2x}{n(n-1)}$. Then give the first person $nk$, the second person $(n-1)k$, and in general, the $i$th person $(n-i+1)k$. note that this means that the total amount given out is $nk+(n-1)k+\ldots+k=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}k=x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've been trying to convert this to code and I have this:

        int people = 10;
        float prize = 1000f;

        int k = (2 * (int)prize) / people * (people-1);

        for ( int i = 0; i < people; ++i )
        {
            Debug.Log((i + 1)*k);
        }

But it's printing out very large values rather than 10 values that total 1000.

Comment: @Cypras Almost certainly in whichever programming language you're using, `2 * (int)prize) / people * (people-1)` computes `2 * (int)prize) / people` and then multiplies that by `(people-1)`. With `int people = 10` that means you multiplied by 9 when you were supposed to divide by 9. Also, by the way, you are using integer arithmetic for the division, which may tend to give you large truncation errors for some inputs (though not in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some simple ways to do it:

If there are $y$ people, you can start by giving $1$ to the $y$th (last) person, $2$ to the $(y-1)$st person (the one before the last), $3$ to the $(y-2)$nd person, and so forth.
By continuing in this way you eventually will give
$(y-1)$ to the second person and $y$ to the first.

If you are allowed to divide the amount $x$ in such a way that the last person gets nothing, then instead of the amounts in the previous paragraph you can give everyone $1$ less: $0$ to the $y$th person, $1$ to the $(y-1)$st person, and so forth, so that you give $(y-1)$ to the first person.

When you have done all this, you will have given a total of $\frac{y(y+1)}2$ if the last person got $1,$ or $\frac{y(y-1)}2$ if the last person got $0.$
If the amount you have already given is greater than the total amount you started with, $x,$ and your job is to give a different integer amount to each of the $y$ people, and you have already given the last person the minimum amount you can ($0$ or $1$ depending on the rules for the distribution), then unfortunately the job is impossible and you must declare failure.

If after giving the amounts already mentioned, there is some amount of the prize remaining, then you just have to give the remaining prize in such a way that you don't give more to the $(k+1)st$ person than you give to the $k$th person.

One way to do this is to just give all the remaining prize to the first person.
There are other methods you can use, of course.
But that choice comes down to any other constraints you have, and when you have satisfied those constraints (if there are any) then it comes down to personal preference.

If you are allowed to give non-integer amounts then as far as the mathematics is concerned, you will always be able to divide the prize as required. Just "scale down" the amounts you give each person so the total does not exceed $x.$ In this case, if you are doing this in software then you should not use "integer" variables in any of your calculations or "cast" any of the variables to integers, because in some cases that will prevent you from getting non-integer results when you need them (for example when $y = 20$ and $x = 100$).