# Prize breakdown formula

Tags: logic

I want to distribute prize among $~10000~$ customers, so we have a ranking system and as per the ranks, percentage should be allocated and prize is distributed.
Suppose Rank1 - 15% , Rank2 -10% ..and so on....
I want the formula to distribute the prize as per the ranks

Comment: Where is the image ?

Comment: sorry sailesh as I am new here so it wouldn't allow me to attach the image. If you have seen Dream11, they distributr prize as per the ranks. I need the same logic

Comment: It would help if there was some reference to the distribution. I'm not familiar with Dream11, for example.

Comment: sure let me give an example, if I have 10000 rs to distribute among 100 users as per there ranks from rank 1 to rank 100    by % depending on the rank so what logic should be applied if rank 1 will be given 2% of 10000 rs, rank 2-will be given 1% of the prize money and accordingly

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3242290/divide-x-into-y-parts-by-decreasing-value

Comment: @meetdhruve okay so what I understood is that the percentage $p=p(r)$ that one receives should be a function of the rank. And obviously it should be a decreasing function. And you also say that $p(r=1) = 2$ and $p(r=2) = 1$. This is good but still doesn't give a definition on how we should proceed with this. Do we halve the percentage every time? Also note that the sum of the percentages should add up to $100$.

Comment: @Matti P. okay lets make it more simple to understand. I have 1000$ as a prize . I want to distribute it to 50 winners out of 100 participants based on ranks.. Rank1 = 15% of prize money, Rank 2 = 10% of prize money Rank 3 to Rank 25 =1% of prize money and so on... This is how I want to distribute the prize in % as per the ranks

Comment: @meetdhruve Thank you for the clarification. However, it's still not clear to me what you want exactly. Now you have changed the percentages and ratios. Is it so that ANY type of distribution (as long as it's decreasing and sums to $100\%$) is okay? I mean, do you have any additional requirements for the function?

Comment: @Matti P that was just an example.The percentage always varies depending on the users joining the contest. Yes it is ok as it's decreasing and sum upto 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to construct a function that sums to $100~\%$ is to use a descending geometric sequence. Let the person with Rank 1 get $a_1$ per cent of the prize. The second will get $a_2 = qa_1$ where $q<1$ is some real number (to be solved). The person with rank 3 will get $a_3 = q^2 a_1$ etc. So the person on Rank $r$ will get $a_1 q^{r-1}$ per cent.

Now, the condition was that the sum of these is equal to $100$:
$$
a_1 + q a_1 + q^2 a_1 + q^3 a_1 + \ldots = 100
$$
$$
a_1 (1+q+q^2 + \ldots) = 100
$$
the expression in the parentheses is a geometric sum and it's easy to show that it equals to $\frac{1}{1-q}$ when $\left| q \right| <1$. So now we have
$$
\frac{a_0}{1-q} = 100 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad q = 1- \frac{a_1}{100}
$$
From this on, it's possible to tweak these parameters to one's liking. For example, we could set $a_1=25$, making $q= 0.75$. In that case, the prize percentages would be
$$
25; \quad 18.75; \quad 14.063; \quad 10.547; \quad 7.91 \quad  \ldots
$$
Is this clear to you? You can change the value of $a_1$ to tweak these numbers.

Comment: Notice that there are $10\,000$ customers, so instead of using $\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k = \frac 1 {1 - q}$ you should be using $\sum_{k=0}^{9999} q^k = \frac {1 - q^{10\,000}} {1 - q}$.

Comment: @LucaBressan While I agree with you, I think using infinitely many customers is not a bad approximation.

Comment: You're right. As long as $a_1 > 0.0921$, the sum of the first $10\,000$ terms of the geometric progression is still greater than $99.99$.